# Best way to deploy PHP site locally

Tags: wamp, deployment

I am running a CMS website using [PyroCMS](https://www.pyrocms.com/) on my Windows machine. I am serving up the pages from my localhost using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

I have two separate directories:

**Development:** C:\Users\me\development\ContentSite\

**Live (Wamp root dir):** C:\wamp\www\

I am developing my PyroCMS theme in the development directory, which has the same directory structure as it would when deployed to the Wamp WWW root.

What is the best way to make a fast deployment script? Essentially it would just need to wipe out the current contents of the Wamp www root directory and replace it with what I have in development. I came up with this script using PowerShell:

```
$from = "C:\Users\me\development\ContentSite\*"
$to = "C:\wamp\www"
Copy-Item $from $to -recurse -force
```

But it is pretty slow. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\me\development\ContentSite\" "C:\wamp\www" /mir` instead. This will only copy changed files.

For more info on robocopy: http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Also take a peak at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677789/powershell-copy-item-but-only-copy-changed-files

Comment: Good stuff. I had forgotten all about ROBOCOPY. This works well.